# How to animate an ImageView without animating its subView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I have two `UIImageViews` called `feedView` and `feedImageIcon`.
`feedImageIcon` is a `subView` of `feedView`.
I am performing a CABasicAnimation with keyPath @"transform.scale.xy" on `feedView`. This animation affects `feedImageIcon` as well.

How do I perform the animation on `feedView` without animating `feedImageIcon`?

I tried adding `feedImageIcon` as `feedView's` subView in the completion of [UIView transitionWithView.....] but it still animates `feedImageIcon`.

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why does it need to be a subview?

Comment: Because `feedView` and `feedImageIcon` need to have 2 different images. I'm trying to animate the `feedView` without animating `feedImageIcon`. So, the `feedImageIcon` remains the same size while `feedView` is performing the CABasicAnimation. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I mean why not just place feedImageIcon on top of feedView, rather than have it as a subview?

Comment: Yeah it is never a good practice to have an imageView inside another imageView. You should place it on top, not inside. Then your animation will work as intended.

Comment: How do I place `feedImageIcon` on top of `feedView`? Sorry if this question sounds amateur-ish.

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you so much @beyowulf and @ShahiM!! I figured out how to place it on top.
Thank you for letting me know that it is bad practice to place an imageview as a subview of another imageview

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @beyowulf and @ShahiM! I was not aware that it is not a good practice to place an `UIImageView` as a subView of another `UIImageView`.

I added `feedImageIcon` as a subView to `self.view` and called `bringSubviewToFront`.

Works exactly how I want it to.

Thanks again!